# Asio read txt file from web server

Tags: c++, asio

**Introduction What I want to do:**

I want get text from file which is on server.
Imagine:
a pseudo code

```
connectTo("https://www.boost.org/LICENSE_1_0.txt");
std::string result = connectTo.GetResult();
std::cout << result;
```

and I should get:

```
Boost Software License - Version 1.0 - August 17th, 2003

Permission is here...
```

---

**What I done:**

I use [Asio](https://think-async.com/Asio/index.html) (not Boost Asio) and this example:

```
    ip::tcp::iostream stream;
    stream.connect("www.boost.org", "http");
    if (!stream)
    {
        std::cout << "Error: " << stream.error().message() << "\n";
    }
    stream << "GET /LICENSE_1_0.txt HTTP/1.0\r\n\r\n";
    stream << "Host: www.boost.org\r\n";
    stream << "Accept: */*\r\n";
    stream << "Connection: close\r\n\r\n";

    for (std::string line; getline(stream, line);)
    {
        std::cout << line << std::endl;
    }
```

and I get this:

```
HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Date: Fri, 12 Jun 2020 12:54:59 GMT
Server: Apache/2.2.15 (CentOS)
Location: https://beta.boost.org/LICENSE_1_0.txt
Content-Length: 326
Connection: close
Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1

<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html><head>
<title>301 Moved Permanently</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Moved Permanently</h1>
<p>The document has moved <a href="https://beta.boost.org/LICENSE_1_0.txt">here<
/a>.</p>
<hr>
<address>Apache/2.2.15 (CentOS) Server at beta.boost.org Port 80</address>
</body></html>
```

---

**What I want:**

instead html I want get text from LICENSE_1_0.txt file. How to do that?

Comment: You have to follow the redirect: `HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently`, `Location: https://beta.boost.org/LICENSE_1_0.txt`

Comment: @Thomas Sablik If I understand it, I should get text, and what I got is "error"? If yes, then it looks like I should use https instead http.

Comment: What error did you get? 301 is not an error. It means that the resource you are looking for has moved. As you can see the whole url has changed, not only https. Your program has to send a request and check the header of the response. If the response code is 301 it has to send a new request to the new location. It has to repeat until the response code is different to 301.

Comment: Basically, if you want to implement HTTP yourself, with your own code, to download stuff from the web server, you have to ...implement HTTP and all parts of it, like cookies and redirects. Even implement SSL correctly, with certificate validation, etc. About 1-3 months of development, I'd estimate.  Or use one of freely-available libraries, like curl, that will do it for you. About an hour of work, I'd estimate. Which approach makes sense to you?

Comment: @Sam Varshavchik I am looking for quick solution. I know CURL, but Asio looks very easy, simply I put header and use it. What I want is only read txt file from web server, I dont need anything special.

Comment: @Thomas Sablik if you go to www.boost.org/LICENSE_1_0.txt in web explorer, you will be redirected in to https://www.boost.org/LICENSE_1_0.txt (https). Therefore I think I should use https. But it need SSL I think, because when I put https insted http, I got information that my explorer not support or something that (it was written in not english).

Comment: Yes, in your example the redirect link is `https://www.boost.org/LICENSE_1_0.txt` but that's not the generic solution. If the response code is 301 you have to read the `Location` header entry and start a new request. That's what your browser does in the background.

Comment: Send a request: `curl -I http://www.boost.org/LICENSE_1_0.txt`. Read the response code `HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently`. Read the location `Location: https://www.boost.org/LICENSE_1_0.txt`. Send a new request: `curl -I https://www.boost.org/LICENSE_1_0.txt`. Get the response code `HTTP/1.1 200 OK`. Read the file from the body.

Comment: @Thomas Sablik does it work on Asio too?

Comment: I don't know Asio but it the diagram shows that it support SSL. Of course you have to handle the redirect yourself.

Comment: Unfortunately, C++ does not have a reputation for offering a "quick solution" for anything. Even though you "don't need any special", in order to talk to a web server the only way to do so is to use a full and complete implementation of HTTP. It doesn't matter how "special" it is, it is still HTTP, with all of its features. If the web server requires the client to correctly handle cookies and redirects, this is what the HTTP client must do, and there's nothing you can do about it. If you only need to talk to one specific server, perhaps some details can be skipped.

Comment: @Sam Varshavchik if i understand you, I don't get any data from text if I'll use SSL (from this code I provided in question)? In reality I need it to check program version from txt file on server. That's all.

Comment: The code in the question does not use SSL. It connects to port 80, http port. The web server responds with a redirect to the https port, since the "txt file on server" is only accessible via https, and SSL. Which part of this explanation you still have questions about? There is no other way to access this file, except via https and SSL. The End.